# Error while iterating over array elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have below array -

```
var arr= [ 
{
 id:1,
 name:"some name 1",
 email:"somename1@email.com"
},
{
 id:2,
 name:"some name 2",
 email:"somename2@email.com"
}
]
```

I want to iterate in a way that , I want output as string (semi colun separated name string)-

```
"some name 1;some name 2"
```

I iterated it in below manner -

```
var name="";
arr.forEach( (item:any)=> {
name+=item.name+";";
});
```

But I am getting below error -

```
UncoughtError : Objects are not valid as react child (found object with keys {id , name , email}). If you want to render collection of child use array instead.
```

**EDIT :**

```
return (
<span> {name} </span>
)
```

Comment: Can you show full component? It seems that you're trying to render an `Object`.

Comment: This code won't trigger that error. Please include the relevant part of your code. Also, is anything about the error message unclear?

Comment: Please include the return statement of the component

Comment: @NeERAJTK please check edit section. I included edit

Comment: @CSharper It should be <span> instead of <Span>

Comment: @NeERAJTK typo.. I have used in small cases only.. <span>

Comment: @CSharper [The code that you shared works properly](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-platform-6k0n1n?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to implement what you're looking for is by using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

You can try out the following code by using ES6:

```js
const arr= [ 
    {
     id:1,
     name:"some name 1",
     email:"somename1@email.com"
    },
    {
     id:2,
     name:"some name 2",
     email:"somename2@email.com"
    }
    ]

const newString = arr.reduce((preVal, newVal) => `${preVal} ${preVal ? ";" : ""} ${newVal.name} `, "")

console.log(newString)
```

Answer (score -1):

The error usually means you're trying to render something that's not directly a React component

Comment: Yes, that does describe the OP's error, but how does this solve the problem?